# When is swap memory useful? Why do we need to set it to twice the amount of RAM?

Tags: linux, memory, swap

I know that memory will be swapped whenever RAM usage is high. And I read that we need to set swap to be twice of the amount of RAM. But why? How will it shift from RAM to swap? If we do not have swap what will happen?

Comment: are you talking about a specific operating system or is it a general question? The answer may vary (but it is not going to be "always double than ram" anyway).

Comment: @pqnet no no am not talking about specifically. am asking the real working nature os SWAP.

Comment: The 2x or 2.5x amount for swap is a bordering on fallacy.  It doesnt hurt to set it that high, but it isnt necessary.  The reality is you only need as much as you actually *need*.  You can monitor your OS over time and see what the peak usage is and there is no reason to go beyond that, unless you change usage habits.

Comment: @Keltari: It does hurt! If your primary storage is an SSD and you have 32GB RAM, which is /not/ unreasonable on a high end machine, then wasting 64GB of space because you're blindly following 1999-era advice is problematic.

Comment: @Phoshi waste and hurt are two separate things

Comment: @Keltari: 25% loss of your primary storage (or worse!) hurts, not just for the user having less storage, but also for the drive having less free space to do load balancing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The swap space is usually used as a replacement for RAM, as in another storage for pages which are in memory, but not necessarily only when you run out of RAM, since RAM too as other usage than being memory for your programs: it is common for modern memory managers to move the memory allocated by programs which are idle in background into swap space and use the newly freed RAM space to cache disk accesses.

Another usage of swap space is to save a snapshot of RAM when doing suspend to disk or hibernate (so that the system can shut down the power from RAM without data loss).

Having swap double than RAM makes sense because, well, if you bought that much ram is because you know you'll need it, so you'd better have a proportional swap space ready as well because you will likely need that too. In modern system it is sufficient to have enough swap space to keep out of the way background idle services which would otherwise clobber the RAM you would use for other more important stuff (unused RAM can always be exploited to cache disk anyway, which speeds up your system A LOT). Some system save memory pages into swap preventively while they are still in RAM, so that if they need to remove them to free a bit of memory they can do it a lot faster (they can be discarded without the need to write them on disk because they are already there). For this reason (and to allow hybernation) it is probably a good idea to have at least enough swap space as the amount of RAM, except for cases in which you have an exceptionally huge amount of RAM and/or a small disk (like SSD drives)

While idle processes' memory can be swapped out, this is not true for active processes: when a process requires a page which has been swapped out, it triggers what is called a *page fault*: the process is paused, memory manager gets the page back into RAM, then the process is resumed and can read/write the required memory. This means that if your working set (i.e., the data which is currently being accessed frequently, by non-idle applications) is bigger than available RAM, you will need to swap in and out pages *almost at every memory read or write*, making the system so slow that it becomes unusable (this is called *thrashing*). So the swap space cannot actually substitute the RAM you are actually using, only the one your processes allocated but they are *not really* using.

Comment: Its giving me much clarity. do you have any idea about buffers on ubuntu(Linux) ?

Comment: @Ramkee, yes see comment on Cfinley's answer

Comment: Thank you for that. just now i have seen. generally we manually do delete cache. but we no need to delete buffers. because it will vanish automatically. am i correct ? suggest me

Comment: you shouldn't manually delete either: the buffers will become cache as soon as the data has been written to disk, and if memory is needed the cache will be immediately tossed away by the kernel (so it is actually the same as if it were free at that moment). Plus, if by some chance the system will need to read those data, it does not need to get them from disk but it can use the copy it already has in memory and load them a lot faster.

Comment: the only usage there is for `/proc/sys/vm/drop_caches` is during performance measurements, for example if you want to measure the speed of your disk (so that you can be sure that the read operation will be done on disk instead that on RAM). If it were a good idea doing that from time to time, don't you think that the linux kernel developers, which know how this stuff works better than me and you, would have done that automatically from time to time?

Comment: what does echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches ?

Comment: look at [this thread](http://www.unix.com/unix-for-advanced-and-expert-users/146367-echo-1-proc-sys-vm-drop_caches-good-idea.html): disabling/cleaning caches makes the system actually slower in most times. Every time I buy a new computer I get as much RAM as possible (within my budget) even if I know that I won't never use even half of them for programs, because allowing the system to use disk caches makes it a lot faster and responsive.

Comment: `echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches` will discard any cache and similar object that duplicates information already present on disk from RAM. What do you mean when you say that you "manually delete cache"? I thought you meant that you use that command from time to time, since some think that will improve their server's performance.

Answer (score 2):

In general, memory is swapped out when you are running out of available memory on the computer.

What basically happens is that the operating system will store some of the contents of the RAM onto the storage drive to make room for other applications' memory needs. How the operating system chooses what to take off of the RAM depends on when it was last accessed. The available space for the operating system to use for swapping is called virtual memory.

The rule of thumb is to have your swap be twice the amount of RAM installed in your computer. However, this may not be the best for you. If you have 2GB of RAM installed, your swap size will be 4GB of virtual memory, giving you a total of 6GB of memory to work with. While 6GB may work for most people, this may not be enough for you.

The downside of swapping memory is that it takes up space on your storage drive. Because it is on the storage drive, accessing information on it will be noticeably slower than if it was on the RAM.

You can get away with have little to no space reserved for your computer to swap on your storage drive. With or without this, if your computer has to remember more than the total memory (physical + virtual memory), it may become unstable. It is important that the computer has more than enough memory to work with.

The operating itself may have additional use for the space as well. For example, Windows. If Windows itself crashes, it saves a crashdump file to the space reserved for the swap. For this reason, I do not recommend completely getting rid of the swap space, but you should check to see what your operating system does with the space first.

Comment: Great answer! so you concluded that swap is a spared memory for the system. am i right ?

Comment: @Ramkee Yes, swap is system reserved for when you use too much memory.

Comment: Actually this is not true anymore. The rule of thumb for windows XP was 1,5 to 3x the memory, but since windows 7 and up, the rule of thumb is to leave the settings as they are, which works better 90% of the time.

Comment: @LPChip True, but that's why I said in general. While I agree that users should leave alone defaults, sometimes it is necessary to tweak these settings. For example, I had a 60GB SSD a few years ago with 16GB of RAM, and Windows took up about 40-50GB of it. Getting rid of hibernation and shrinking/moving the pagefile helped.

Comment: Thanks for the nice info. and can you tell me what buffers can do in between RAM and SWAP.is buffer for temporary storage? if it is then already RAM is there for temporary storage.. what actually it does?

Comment: @Ramkee What do you mean by "buffers"? The only thing I can think of that makes sense is a range for the swap size. For more information about swapping, check out [this](http://lifehacker.com/5426041/understanding-the-windows-pagefile-and-why-you-shouldnt-disable-it) lifehacker page. It talks about the Windows side of it, but it applies to other OSs as well.

Comment: @Cfinley I have 12 GB of ram, and system management in windows 7 sets this to 12 to 18 GB, where 12 is used. Nothing like 40 gb as you describe. Besides, you can set the swapfile to a different drive and still have it system-managed.

Comment: @Cfinley oh sorry i forgot to mention. When we use linux machine there we can see buffers. if you run the command free -m in linux box. There we can found buffers. am talking about these buffers

Comment: @LPChip The Windows installation, hybernation, pagefiles, ect. files were taking up the 40-50GB total, not just pagefile. I should have made that more clear. Sorry about the confusion. This was around 3 years ago, so I can't remember the exact numbers that Windows was telling me. Also, feel free to edit my answer if parts of it are not correct by today's standards.

Comment: @Ramkee I am not familiar enough with Linux to give you an answer that I am comfortable with. You could try asking another question about these buffers on your distro's forums. ([Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/) for instance).

Comment: @Ramkee the buffer/cache in linux's `free` command refers to the amount of RAM that is used to cache the disk. I think "buffer" means  write cache and "cache" means read cache. See http://www.linuxatemyram.com . It is memory that can be considered as "free" because it can be discarded at any time (since there is a copy on disk already), it is data kept there only because it _may become useful_ later on.